# Phabricator hook and Bitbucket

Tags: git, hook, bitbucket, phabricator

My desired setup it is to have my repos in bitbucket and then a copy in phabricator to use its tasks manager and diff features.

After setting up correctly the server and bitbucket I can pull any repo and it is updated, but as the documentation states it is possible that a repository is updated and yet phabricator takes some time to notice and therefore close tasks, update the repo, show diff, etc... To solve this  issue they say a hook can be used in the primary repo to tell phabricator to update as soon as it can. The problem is that I don't know how to configure bitbucket to post the JSON against my machine when I push commits to it (bitbucket).

Can anybody help me with that or it is not possible and I need some kind of workaround?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The API you are looking for is:
https://secure.phabricator.com/conduit/method/diffusion.looksoon/

Now indeed, BitBucket does not allow to send custom request content so all you could do is call a custom API on your server that would then do the conduit call itself. A bit of an overkill somehow...

Now, I would try to take the problem in the other way:
Why not setting up your repository as a phabricator hosted repository that would push changes to the bitbucket automatically,
This wouldn't require any kind of hook.